# Is there a mathematical operation to ensure that two vectors are perfectly equal?

Tags: vector-spaces, numerical-methods

Let's said that I have a 3D matrix of integer of size 10x10x4, I want to know if along the 3rd dimension some vectors are perfectly similar (same number, same order).

So I could compare one by one each vectors (of size 4) with each others. But I'm using a computer and the time matters. So is there a mathematical operation to ensure that two vectors are perfectly equal. Or, same question others words, is there a mathematical operation that can link a unique value to a unique vector.

So typicaly for a vector of size 4 (base 10) the associated number should be between 1 and 10^4 (ideally).

Comment: If you assign some unique value to each vector then you have to compare those values. For a computer comparing a vector (as in sequence of bytes) and comparing a number is pretty much the same thing. I don't see any gain in doing that (except for a given language limitations). If you don't know anything about the matrix then the only sensible thing is to compare row by row. This can be parallelized though (even on gpu).

Comment: However if you expect that those matrices are often not going to be perfectly similar (which, as I've mentioned is something you have to know a priori) and those vectors are big then I guess hashing is an option. Although it can give you false positives.

Comment: A matrix is two-dimensional.  You're talking about a three-dimensional array.  It's not any different from determining if two members of a one-dimensional array are identical.  The fastest thing to do, so far as I know, is to sort the array and then compare adjacent elements.  (This is on a single CPU.)

Comment: you are using a computer so you can write a function that converts a vector with four components into a string with separators: $"v1;v2;v3;v4"$ and make comparison based on the results of this function

Comment: @Vasya that's a *really bad idea*. you are increasing the size of the data to parse, not reducing it

Comment: @Federico: I do not see how this is different from concatenating binary representations of the components. The goal is to compare a single value instead of four comparisons.

Comment: @Vasya because the binary representation is already the most compact for you can have for that data. If you print out in decimal digits, you waste a lost of space.

Comment: @Vasya A 4D vector of `double`s is `4*64=256` bits. When printed out, every double requires around `16` digits. So you have `4*16*8=512` bits.

Comment: @Federico: Maybe, but how do you concatenate binary representation? By converting it to a string? This will waste more space.

Comment: @Vasya No. Ultimately, you will use something like `int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);` ([man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html)), both to do the comparison of the binary representation of doubles or to compare printed out strings. So what matter is that the size of your data is as small as possible

Comment: @Federico: to use memcmp you need all four values to be allocated sequentially in memory. We'll have to agree to disagree on this.

Comment: @Vasya Well I very much hope that the OP matrix is in row order to start with. In any case, I said "somethink like" `memcmp`. You can very easily implement a function that tests equality of 4 non consecutive (but strided) `double`s. The crucial thing is that I compare less data this way than if I printed out the arrays. That's just useless and nonsensical

Comment: @Vasya it doesn't matter if a row is a sequence in memory or not. Comparing bytes directly will always be faster then stringifying numbers (note that you need to traverse the matrix as well, regardless of how it is arranged) and then comparing strings. You do at least twice the work.

Answer (score 1):

If by "number" you allow [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) then of course to the vector $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ you can associate $v_1+iv_2+jv_3+kv_4$, but that is not helpful at all...

If you know for instance that the entries are integers, then you can send $v$ to $v_1+\sqrt2 v_2+\sqrt3 v_3 + \sqrt5 v_4$ and this would be a bijection.

You have to consider if you are interested in $v=w$ or rather $|v-w|<10^{-8}$, because the two "equalities" are quite different to test. For instance, you cannot hash the vectors in order to test the second one.

Otherwise, if you think about it, the bit representation of the floating points for the components of $v$ are already a number associated to the vector. You just associate to $v$ the binary number obtained from the concatenation of the binary representations of $v_1,\dots,v_4$.

Given that the vectors are very short (only 4 entries), I don't see any real benefit of attempting anything different from pairwise comparison.
You can use something like `int memcmp(const void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);` ([manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html)) for that or trivially code your own.

If you know something more about the spacial distribution of your vectors, maybe you can try something like [hextrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) in order to reduce the number of necessary comparisons.

See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning) for ideas on how to partition your vectors.
For instance, given $w\in\mathbb R^4$, you can partition your vector in the two families $W_-=\{v:v\cdot w<0\}$ and $W_+=\{v:v\cdot w>0\}$. Now you only need to check for identity among the two families and not across them. So if you are able to find a good $w$ that splits your vectors in two families approximately equinumerous, you pass from $n^2$ tests to $n^2/2$.

**Edit** Taking further the previous idea of computing $w\cdot v$,
you can in fact compute `10x10` matrix of these scalar product and then have to worry only about entries which are the same. This can reduce drastically the number of comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a hash function in the general sense.  Let a vector be $(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3)$.  If you know all the components are positive and less than some number $b$, you can just compute $a_0+ba_1+b^2a_2+b^3a_3$ and compare these.  That gets you what you want, a unique number for each vector as long as they are what you expect.  Whether it is worth computing this for each vector is up to you.  I would be surprised if this is the slow point for your code.  Of course, if $b$ is the size of the largest number that fits in an int you haven't saved any storage at all.

If you don't know the size of your vectors but all the components are positive whole numbers you can use the [Cantor Pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).  You can find many mentions of it on the site.  You can pair $a_0 $ and $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$ and finally the two pairs.  This is more computation but handles numbers of any size.  If you have negative numbers you need to make them positive some what or adapt the function.

Comment: That's wrong. Hashing **does not** give a unique number for a row. No such function can exist if the size of vector is greater then the size of the hash.

Comment: @freakish:  hashing as a general term, does apply in the sense of taking many numbers and making one.  The base representation and the pairing function are included.  They will give unique results when given the proper input.